# Object property UNDEFINED in VUE v-for

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this object  inside an array called places which contains 20 similar objects
and im using `v-for` to get each objects data into a div, other properties work fine, but when it comes to the `openingHours.text` property, it gives an error of undefined

```
{
  ...

  "openingHours": {
    "text": "lun.-sam.: 23:59 - 23:59",
    "label": "Heures d'ouverture",
    "isOpen": false,
    "structured": [
      {
        "start": "T235900",
        "duration": "PT24H00M",
        "recurrence": "FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

you can check the images below for more clarity

[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob9ri.png)

[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0T60.png)

Comment: Is it possible that `openingHours` type of string? Maybe it's not an object. Can you print it in Console?

Comment: no i checked it and it says object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does every object have `place.openingHours.text` ?
If not you can try with:

```
place.openingHours?.text
```

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks alot

Comment: @Mohamed MOUYAHADA You are welcome mate, cheers :)